# File upload failed while uploading into dropbox in iOS in CoreApI

Tags: dropbox

I'm failing to upload files into dropbox in iOS in CoreApI

I'm getting this message

> [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to
>   /1/files_put/sandboxsandbox/helloworld.txt - (400) Expected 'root' to
>   be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto', got u'sandboxsandbox' 2013-12-04
>   18:23:57.348 DropBoxCore[4914:907] File upload failed with error -
>   Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (dropbox.com error 400.)" UserInfo=0x22b1d7f0
>   {sourcePath=/var/mobile/Applications/28B2865A-58BC-4DC8-8E61-7F40307DDC56/DropBoxCore.app/helloworld.txt,
>   destinationPath=sandbox/helloworld.txt, error=Expected 'root' to be
>   'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto', got u'sandboxsandbox'}

Could someone please help me, I have searched for this, but couldn't find any solutions for this problem.

Comment: This is a pretty poor question that amounts to debug-this-for-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you shared your code, but my guess is that your passing in a path like `sandbox/helloworld.txt` and should instead pass `/helloworld.txt`. If that's not it, please do share your code.

Answer (score 2):

From the Dropbox [docs for file_put](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put):

> #### URL Structure
>
> ```
> https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/<root>/<path>?param=val
> ```
>
> **root** The root relative to which path is specified. Valid values are *sandbox*
>   and *dropbox*.
>
> **path** The path to the file you want to retrieve.

A key bit of information in your error message is the path portion of the URI made in the request. Relevant line from your error message:

```
error making request to /1/files_put/sandboxsandbox/helloworld.txt
```

Compared to the URL structure from the docs, for `<root>` you've used `sandboxsandbox`, but the docs say only `sandbox` and `dropbox` are valid values.

The error in the JSON response body has a similar clue:

```
error=Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto', got u'sandboxsandbox'
```

Referring to the API docs is unnecessary as the error message spells out that `sandboxsandbox` isn't among the list of valid values for *root*.

Though slightly less obvious, this bit in the JSON when compared to the URL structure and the documentation gives a hint:

```
destinationPath=sandbox/helloworld.txt
```

After a small leap that *destinationPath* corresponds to *path* in the API docs and reading that *root* is "the root relative to which path is specified" you can surmise that the path shouldn't contain the root. Whether it should be `/helloworld.txt` or `helloworld.txt` can be deduced by seeing that the URL structure already accounts for a `/` between `<root>` and `<path>`. Compare these expansions using `/helloworld.txt` and `helloworld.txt` respectively:

```
/1/files_put/<root>/<path>
/1/files_put/sandbox/<path>
/1/files_put/sandbox//helloworld.txt

/1/files_put/<root>/<path>
/1/files_put/sandbox/<path>
/1/files_put/sandbox/helloworld.txt
```

It should be clear which value of *path* is correct.

Comment: Poor questions sometimes deserve good answers. And even I'm guilty of asking questions for which the answer is in the error message right before my eyes and explained in the docs...javac warnings *cough cough*